# Libgdx | Box2D | Poll if body collides with another

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

I want to be able to at any point in my code test if two bodies collide. I know about the contact listener, but since I am destroying/recreating body fixtures every frame, that wont work for me. How can I test if bodies collide kinda like you can poll for input using Gdx.input.isKeyPressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to realize this is to calculate the distance between these two bodies. You can also include the width and height.

Something like the following (Kotlin):

```
if (bodyA.position.dst(bodyB.position.x, bodyB.position.y) <= 50f)
    //bodyA has contact with bodyB
```

Comment: I would say yes, but you have to try it of course. It depends on how fast your refresh time is: [Stepping the simulation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Box2d#stepping-the-simulation)

Comment: One problem is that this doesn't account for rotation. My objects are all rotated around the center of the screen.